# Git sample project "pubsub-appengine-sample" project is showing ERROR: Directories are not supported

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I got the code from the git repository  and tried to run that code as per the `readme.md` instruction, but nothing works for me getting mojoException. I run as project using maven with `gcloud:run` and `gcloud:deploy` command. full details Error message is given below  ---

```
Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [pubsub-appengine-sample] in [E:\OfficeCode\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\war]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [E:\OfficeCode\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [78 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: E:\OfficeCode\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\war.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gcloud-maven-plugin:1.9.17:run (default-cli) @ pubsub-appengine-sample <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gcloud-maven-plugin:1.9.17:run (default-cli) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Running gcloud app run...
May 21, 2015 2:19:38 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed E:\OfficeCode\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target/war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
[INFO] Running C:\python27_x64\python.exe -S C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py --project=halogen-proxy-87911 preview app run E:\OfficeCode\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target/war
[INFO] ERROR: Directories are not supported [E:\OfficeCode\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target/war].  You must provide explicit yaml files.
[INFO] ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.run) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
[ERROR] Error: gcloud app xxx exit code is: 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.938 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-21T14:19:54+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/179M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:1.9.17:run (default-cli) on project pubsub-appengine-sample: Error: gcloud app xxx exit code is: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

suggest me what i am doing wrong ?  source of code is Git repository link is given below

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/tree/master/appengine-push

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting and sorry for the breakage. I will fix this soon.

Edit (May 23): Now the gcloud maven plugin works again. Please pull the latest change from the repo. Unfortunately the authentication on the local emulator is not working right now. For a time being, you can deploy the app to the cloud (mvn gcloud:deploy) to see the app working. I will update once the local authentication issue is fixed.

Comment: Still not working for me  : `code`  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (validate) on project pubsub-appengine-sample: Failed during checkstyle execution: There are 11 errors reported by Checkstyle 6.1.1 with checkstyle.xml ruleset. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: The checkstyle:check phase passes for me. Did you modify the source code? If so, look at those 11 errors and fix them so that the app should be able to run.

Comment: Thanks Now I am able to  run the code without any problem. checkstyle is showing error in "length line" and "a newline at the end of file" which i ignored using `<module name="LineLength">
          <property name="severity" value="ignore" />   
            
        </module> ` and selecting default eclipse Window>preference>checkStyle default sun_checks_eclipse.xml  .

Comment: Still have some doubt :  1. deployed application taking default time 20150527t111213 as the version  even i mention the version =10  in appengine.xml          2.  loaded Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for pubsub.js   ----------------     
angular.min.js:29 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=pubsub&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A427)

Comment: I can not reproduce that problem. I think you made some changes to the repo before deploying it. Can you share the change with me?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/blob/master/appengine-push/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/client/demos/appengine/servlet/package-info.java  changed the `package appengine/.../util` to `appengine/.../servlet` and ignore the checkstyle using`<module name="LineLength"> <property name="severity" value="ignore" /> </module> `  and nothing else

Comment: after deploying i am getting 404 for pubsub.js and `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` for angularjs.[link] (http://20150601t115455.halogen-proxy-87911.appspot.com/)

Comment: Working fine pubsub file is not found so i Just copy past all code of Pubsub in the Script tag of the main.jsp and code start working.